# How can I force Google to show my domain, not my IP?

Tags: google, url

I submitted a site to Google using [their tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url).

At the time I didn't actually have a domain for the site, so I just used the IP address.

Later I bought a domain, but Google still seem to be showing the version with the IP address before the domain one.

How do I get it to stop showing the IP address version?

Answer (score 7):

Do a 301 redirect from the IP address to the domain. If you're using Apache you can place this snippet in a file called *.htaccess* placed inside your root web directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^121\.12\.12\.123
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How long do you need to wait for this to work?

Comment: The redirect would take effect immediately.  Google would start showing the domain name in the search results within a few days of crawling a page.  It might take two or three weeks for Google to crawl all the pages on your site.